# Verify Lazy Loading in Angular 7 PROD application

Tags: angular

I want to verify lazy loading in Angular 7.
While on local server, I used https://augury.rangle.io/ browser plugin to verify the lazy loading. Also, verified that the lazy loaded module gets downloaded when I hit the intended router path in address bar.

However, as I deployed the application to prod (ng build --prod), I can't see the lazy-loaded-module.js being downloaded.

Did I make any mistake ? How do I verify it is working correctly ? Should the **module.js download on PROD as well as like on local server ?

PFB screenshot of my dev tools on localhost.
[image]

Added my production config.

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            },
            {
              "replace": "src/index.html",
              "with": "src/index.prod.html"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Comment: This should also work in production..?

Comment: Can you share the production config from angular.json file i think "outputHashing": "all" is missing in your config

Comment: @MikeOne, I mean whether prod server with  build behaves the same as like dev server run with ng serve, as there could be differences or the behaviour could be different (at least in appearance such that i don't see the module js file being downloaded but it is getting lazy loaded under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

please check rout of load module js file from dist,
check address js load module file in runtime.js in dist folder , because address of load in localhost different with published project on host.